# matplotlib subplot axis label

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have a subplot, its x-axis label uses voltages, its csv data column values increase from 0 to 30 and then decrease from 30 to 0.
when I use this code it gives me this plot

```
ax2.plot(df_raw.index, df_raw.loc[:,"data_column"])
```

[image: Matplolib subplot]

When I use below code I got the plot as as shown below

```
ax2.plot(df_raw.loc[:,"voltage"], df_raw.loc[:,"data_column"])
```

[image]

What I really want is as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the label manually:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'vol': list(range(101)) + list(range(99,0,-1)),
                   'val': [0]*10 + [1]*180 +[0]*10})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df.index, df.val)

ax.set_xticklabels(df.vol[ax.get_xticks()]
                 .fillna(0).astype(int))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Never set the ticklabels without setting the ticks. Also don't index an array by the ticks if you didn't control if those ticks are at integer positions previously.